# Cannot comment on my own question and its answers after it was migrated

Tags: support

My "account" says I have asked no questions, but I'm specifically asking about the question I asked to the Statistics board, which was moved to SO.

[How do I subset for specific transfers (A to/from B pairs) in a long list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705128)

I initially was able to comment on a comment to the question.  This is the expected behavior.  I can no longer comment on that "chain", nor can I comment on a proposed Answer that does not work.  I can only check Feedback if it is Useful Y/N, or edit the Question/Answer.  I tried to Edit the Answer, but this was apparently rejected.  I don't know why, and cannot make use of the site without knowing the "rules".

Am I supposed to join in a discussion (a chain of comments) to the Original question and proposed answers or am I supposed to serially modify (Edit) the Question and Answers to add the information?

Comment: You have an unregistered account on [stats.se] and a registered one on [so]. The question belongs to the former.

Answer (score 6):

You don't currently own the question, so you can't comment, edit it, or accept answers. It still belongs to your [unregistered account over at Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/9824/rwfarley).

What you need to do is access your unregistered account, and log in with the same OpenID that you used to create an account here and on Stack Overflow. This *should* automatically associate your accounts and make you own your question again.

If you've lost access to the account used to originally ask the question, then there's a certain problem. You'll need to create a new account on Stats and request that it be merged with your original, unregistered one.

Comment: I managed to get access to my unregistered account by clicking on the activation email on on **the same** computer as I asked the original (anonymous) question. Guess it had to have some cookies.

Comment: To merge two accounts, fill in the form by clicking on the `click here` link on the [user merge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) page if you have lost access to the one. May take a couple of days for a human to attend